# Отслеживание события нажатия кнопки

Tags: c#

Как мы можем отловить событие нажатия кнопки?
Я пытался сделать что-то вроде

```
public delegate void But_Click();
public event But_Click button_click1;
```

Но не получается. Даже если делать событие кнопки public все равно не видит. Может есть другие варианты отследить нажатие кнопки ? При нажатии у меня кнопка запускает работать блок программы. Но в этом блоке еще есть цикл. То есть я хочу когда цикл дойдет до последней строчки там будет метод который будет ждать нажатия кнопки, и при нажатии будет запускать следующую итерацию цикла.

Comment: MyButton.Click += MyMethod - так не работает?

Comment: Нет, так не работает

Comment: Что за кнопка у вас? WinForms проект или что?

Comment: Да, Winforms. Кнопка обычная button

Comment: 2 раза кликните по ней в дизайнере и он создаст подписчик автоматически.

Comment: Так у меня есть в коде кнопка

Answer (score 1):

Нет нужды мудрить с делегатами. Можно создать отдельный метод и подписаться им к событию клика.

```
Button1.Click += YourHandler;

public void YourHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    // Реакция на нажатие
}
```

А еще проще будет через лямду

```
 Button1.Click += (sender,e) => { /* Вызов своего метода или какая-то логика */};
```

Comment: Вот смотрите. 

                  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    ask_label.Text = list[i].Question;
                    Question1.Text = list[i].Answer1;
                    Question2.Text = list[i].Answer2;
                    Question3.Text = list[i].Answer3;
                    button1.Click += (sender,e) => { continue; };
                }
Выбивает ошибку мол continue не может быть в этом блоке, и ошибка на sender мол нельзя объявить в локальной области т.к используется для определения параметра

Comment: Вы пытаетесь пропустит итерацию внешнего цикла в теле события. Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: так в том то и дело что мне всего то по нажатию кнопки нужно пропустить итерацию.

Comment: Для этого нужно добавить внешнюю переменную flag, который поменяется с false на true, когда вы нажмёте кнопку.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь переизобрести `MessageBox`?